# Лучший способ как можно найти key обьекта и получить его значения в переборе массива

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив

```
items = ['name', 'description', ...];
```

и есть массив обьектов

```
objArr = [
  name: {
    required: true,
    title: 'some name'
  },
  description: {
    required: false,
    text: 'some text'
  }
]
```

как можно сделать новый массив чтобы он был таким:

```
itemsInfo = [
  name: {
    name: 'name',
    settings: {
      required: true,
      title: 'some name'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'description',
    settings: {
      required: false,
      text: 'some text'
    }
  },
]
```

я сделал вот таким способом но возможно есть получше решение, так как в моём случает я много раз прохожу в поиске значений?

```
newArr = items.map(item => {
      for (const key in objArr) {
          if (item.name === key) {
             item.field = objArr[key];
          }
      }
      return item;
});
```

Comment: я не понял, зачем вам items - вы же просто имя свойства переносите

Comment: лишнее написал, убрал ту строчку

Comment: вам нужно в порядке, который в items7

Comment: желательно да но не критично

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то за один проход можно сделать. Я не делал, но возможно надо проверять на наличие ключа в objArr

```js
items = ['name', 'description'];

objArr = {
  name: {
    required: true,
    title: 'some name'
  },
  description: {
    required: false,
    text: 'some text'
  }
}

var newArr = [];
for (var i of items) {
   newArr.push({
       name: i,
       setting: objArr[i]
     });
}
console.log(newArr)
```